# Fast 3D interpolation of atmospheric data in Numpy/Scipy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate 3D atmospheric data from one vertical coordinate to another using Numpy/Scipy.  For example, I have cubes of temperature and relative humidity, both of which are on constant, regular pressure surfaces.  I want to interpolate the relative humidity to constant temperature surface(s).

The exact problem I am trying to solve has been asked previously [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312665/how-to-improve-performance-when-interpolating-on-3d-data-with-scipy), however, the solution there is very slow.  In my case, I have approximately 3M points in my cube (30x321x321), and that method takes around 4 minutes to operate on one set of data.

That post is nearly 5 years old.  Do newer versions of Numpy/Scipy perhaps have methods that handle this faster?  Maybe new sets of eyes looking at the problem have a better approach?  I'm open to suggestions.

EDIT:

Slow = 4 minutes for one set of data cubes.  I'm not sure how else I can quantify it.

The code being used...

```
def interpLevel(grid,value,data,interp='linear'):
    """
    Interpolate 3d data to a common z coordinate.

    Can be used to calculate the wind/pv/whatsoever values for a common
    potential temperature / pressure level.

    grid : numpy.ndarray
       The grid. For example the potential temperature values for the whole 3d
       grid.

    value : float
       The common value in the grid, to which the data shall be interpolated.
       For example, 350.0

    data : numpy.ndarray
       The data which shall be interpolated. For example, the PV values for
       the whole 3d grid.

    kind : str
       This indicates which kind of interpolation will be done. It is directly
       passed on to scipy.interpolate.interp1d().

    returns : numpy.ndarray
       A 2d array containing the *data* values at *value*.

    """
    ret = np.zeros_like(data[0,:,:])
    for yIdx in xrange(grid.shape[1]):
        for xIdx in xrange(grid.shape[2]):
            # check if we need to flip the column
            if grid[0,yIdx,xIdx] > grid[-1,yIdx,xIdx]:
                ind = -1
            else:
                ind = 1
            f = interpolate.interp1d(grid[::ind,yIdx,xIdx], \
                data[::ind,yIdx,xIdx], \
                kind=interp)
            ret[yIdx,xIdx] = f(value)
    return ret
```

EDIT 2:
I could share npy dumps of sample data, if anyone was interested enough to see what I am working with.

Comment: Define "slow" and post the code that you're using.  It's hard to provide helpful suggestions to questions with vague details.

Comment: You can probably move the column flip out of the double loop, using a numpy mask. Something like: `mask = grid[0, ...] > grid[-1, ...]; grid[:, mask] = grid[::-1, mask]` (untested).

Comment: take a look at [numba](http://numba.pydata.org).

Comment: It sounds like you want `scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates` (or perhaps the recently added `scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator` both do basically the same thing).  I don't have time for a full answer right now, but if your original data is on a regular grid, there's no need for much more expensive methods.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is atmospheric data, I imagine that your grid does not have uniform spacing; however if your grid is rectilinear (such that each vertical column has the same set of z-coordinates) then you have some options.

For instance, if you only need linear interpolation (say for a simple visualization), you can just do something like:

```
# Find nearest grid point
idx = grid[:,0,0].searchsorted(value)
upper = grid[idx,0,0]
lower = grid[idx - 1, 0, 0]
s = (value - lower) / (upper - lower)
result = (1-s) * data[idx - 1, :, :] + s * data[idx, :, :]
```

(You'll need to add checks for `value` being out of range, of course).For a grid your size, this will be extremely fast (as in tiny fractions of a second)

You can pretty easily modify the above to perform cubic interpolation if need be; the challenge is in picking the correct weights for non-uniform vertical spacing.

The problem with using scipy.ndimage.map_coordinates is that, although it provides higher order interpolation and can handle arbitrary sample points, it does assume that the input data be uniformly spaced. It will still produce smooth results, but it won't be a reliable approximation.

If your coordinate grid is not rectilinear, so that the z-value for a given index changes for different x and y indices, then the approach you are using now is probably the best you can get without a fair bit of analysis of your particular problem.

UPDATE:

One neat trick (again, assuming that each column has the same, not necessarily regular, coordinates) is to use `interp1d` to extract the weights doing something like follows:

```
NZ = grid.shape[0]
zs = grid[:,0,0]
ident = np.identity(NZ)
weight_func = interp1d(zs, ident, 'cubic')
```

You only need to do the above once per grid; you can even reuse weight_func as long as the vertical coordinates don't change.

When it comes time to interpolate then, `weight_func(value)` will give you the weights, which you can use to compute a single interpolated value at `(x_idx, y_idx)` with:

```
weights = weight_func(value)
interp_val = np.dot(data[:, x_idx, y_idx), weights)
```

If you want to compute a whole plane of interpolated values, you can use `np.inner`, although since your z-coordinate comes first, you'll need to do:

```
result = np.inner(data.T, weights).T
```

Again, the computation should be practically immediate.

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions.  With the holiday, it will be Monday before I can test them out.

Comment: These suggestions, while greatly appreciated, will not work for my data.  The data vary non-linearly and non-monotonically in all three dimensions, so it appears that I am stuck with creating a 1D interpolation function at each x,y.

Comment: The techniques above work fine if the `data` array is not monotonic or linear, but do you mean the values in `grid` are not monotonic for given x and y indices? Hmmm - if that's the case, it's not clear that interp1d is appropriate (it is meant for approximating single-valued functions, and will sort it's input so that the first array is increasing).

Comment: I'm probably not doing a very good job of explaining the problem.  I'm a meteorologist, turned hack programmer.  ;-)  Going up a single column (grid[:,x,y]) the values in `grid` and `data` will vary up and down and non-linearly.  Does that help?

Comment: The problem I see is that interp1d requires monotonically increasing inputs for it's first argument, so if grid[:, xIdx, yIdx] is not strictly increasing (possibly after you flip it), then the result you are getting from interp1d is already flawed' you can't really use spline interpolation in that case.

Comment: Doesn't the `assume_sorted=False` argument take care of that?  It's basically moot anyway, as I've found that running `interp1d` >100k times is prohibitively slow.  The only way I've found to do this in a reasonable amount of time is to iterate up the cube, looking for points where `grid[z,...] < value < grid[z-1,...]` OR `grid[z,...] > value > grid[z-1,...]` (since it could be either), finding the slope similar to what you did in your very first suggestion and applying that to the `data`.

Answer (score 1):

This is quite an old question but the best way to do this nowadays is to use MetPy's `interpolate_1d` funtion:

https://unidata.github.io/MetPy/latest/api/generated/metpy.interpolate.interpolate_1d.html

Answer (score 0):

There is a new implementation of [Numba](https://numba.pydata.org/) accelerated interpolation on regular grids in 1, 2, and 3 dimensions:
https://github.com/dbstein/fast_interp

Usage is as follows:

```py
from fast_interp import interp2d
import numpy as np

nx = 50
ny = 37
xv, xh = np.linspace(0, 1,       nx, endpoint=True,  retstep=True)
yv, yh = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, ny, endpoint=False, retstep=True)
x, y = np.meshgrid(xv, yv, indexing='ij')

test_function = lambda x, y: np.exp(x)*np.exp(np.sin(y))
f = test_function(x, y)
test_x = -xh/2.0
test_y = 271.43
fa = test_function(test_x, test_y)

interpolater = interp2d([0,0], [1,2*np.pi], [xh,yh], f, k=5, p=[False,True], e=[1,0])
fe = interpolater(test_x, test_y)
```